# linux shell script case parameter input

Tags: linux, shell, input, parameters, case

people. I want to make a script in linux with two optinos to user choose a manner to take some data from several files. I'm trying this:

```
while [ "$1" != "" ]; do

case $1 in
    -o | --opth) grep OPTH *dk.lis | sed 's/eV_3dk.lis:### OPTICAL THEOREM CROSS SECTION###  OPTH= /   /g' | sort -g; 
                 shift       ;;
    -i | --inel) grep REACT *dk.lis | sed 's/eV_3dk.lis:### INELASTIC CROSS SECTION###  REACT= /   /g' | sort -g;
                shift        ;;
esac
shift
```

done

However, the script returns

> while: Expression Syntax.

I know the functions work good in different scripts, but I would like to use only one script to the both.
Can anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
while [ "$1" != "" ] ; do

case $1 in
    -o | --opth) grep OPTH *dk.lis | sed 's/eV_3dk.lis:### OPTICAL THEOREM CROSS SECTION###  OPTH= /   /g' | sort -g; 
                 shift       ;;
    -i | --inel) grep REACT *dk.lis | sed 's/eV_3dk.lis:### INELASTIC CROSS SECTION###  REACT= /   /g' | sort -g;
                shift        ;;
esac
shift
done
```

Comment: Thanks for help, but your suggestion is the same I tried, maybe with the "done" I miss to put in the block with the code. Of course, I must close the 'while' with 'done', I have sure that is not the problem.